# C# program crashes when using autocomplete in TextBox

Tags: c#

My program crashes sometimes when I type something in the textbox, but sometimes it does not crash...

```
private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t = sender as TextBox;

    if (t != null)
    {
        // say you want to do a search when user types 1 or more chars
        if (t.Text.Length >= 1)
        {
            this.textBox4.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(Artikel);
        }
    }
}
```

`Artikel` is a string array with a bunch of names

```
string[] Artikel;
```

The problem is that its a 50/50 thing, sometimes it crashes and sometimes it doesn't, even with the same characters I type inside the textbox.

Comment: You need not add the string collection inside the textChanged event handler. You need to do it only when you create the TextBox control.

Comment: Forgot to say that the collection in Artikel changes, names can be deleted and added in Artikel. Thats why its in the code.

Comment: You are giving the 'reference' of the string array to the `AddRange` function, so it will be dynamic..if new entries are added, it will reflect in auto complete list. Try it.

Comment: I added the code inside `textBox6_MouseClick` now it does not crash. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as answer, to complete the Q&A, and so that others find the solution.

The OP has moved the assignment of the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` property to the  `MouseClick` event handler instead of setting it inside the `TextChanged` event handler.